How to create graph for higher order derivative in Tensorflow
My target is to forcing gradients to be statistically indistinguishable across tasks in a multi-task model by exposing them into a discriminator (inspired by Adversarial Learning, training weights to make it indistinguishable in the discriminator). But I encounter several problems while implementing it in tensorflow.
So here's the simple overview of my model:
share_embedding = tf.concat(embeddings)
concat_embedding_task1 = tf.concat([share_embedding, diff_embedding1], -1)
concat_embedding_task2 = tf.concat([share_embedding, diff_embedding2], -1)

output_task1 = dense_tower(name='tower1', concat_embedding_task1, nn_units_task1)
output_task2 = dense_tower(name='tower2', concat_embedding_task2, nn_units_task2)

loss_task1 = BCELoss(pred=output_task1, label=label1)
loss_task2 = BCELoss(pred=output_task2, label=label2)
total_loss = loss_task1 + loss_task2

I use tf.gradientTape to get the gradients of each task which flows back to share_embedding, like this:
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    ......
    ......
    grad_1 = tape1.gradient(loss_task1, share_embedding)
    grad_2 = tape1.gradient(loss_task2, share_embedding)
    grad_share = tf.where(flag_task, grad_1, grad_2)

    disc_logits = dense_tower(name='discriminator_layer', grad_share, nn_units_disc)
    disc_loss = BCELoss(pred=disc_logits, label=flag_task)

But when I get the loss of discriminator, I start to wonder how can I make the gradient from disc_loss flows back to share_embedding. The input of discriminator grad_share is already in the backpropagation process of the net, how can I have another gradient(grad_{disc_loss}) backpropagate again following the origin backpropagation route?
After searching for solution, I assume that higher order derivative is useful. Let share_embedding be x, the usual backpropagate gradient is dLoss/dx, and the gradient of discriminator can be calculated as dLoss_disc/dx, but I'm not sure if I can use tape.gradient(disc_loss, share_embedding) to implement, and how can I apply it to share_embedding along with origin dLoss/dx.
I search for the implementation of the original paper of this method in github (link), it's pytorch code, seems quite concise and simple, I consider the very code of the second backpropagation is in here:
grads[task] = grad(curr_loss, features[task], create_graph=True)[0]
grads_norm = grads[task].norm(p=2, dim=1).unsqueeze(1) + 1e-10
input_dscr = grads[task] / grads_norm
outputs_dscr[task] = self.discriminator(input_dscr)

when 'create_graph=True', graph of the derivative will be constructed, allowing to compute higher order derivative products, it means that gradients automatically flows to features[task] aka. share_embedding from discriminator output.
So my question is, how can I recording the second gradient of the gradient itself, to accomplish the same effect like grad(loss, feature, create_graph=True) in pytorch does?
Thank you very much!
